# DBFit java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type İNT is not supported

Tags: java, fitnesse, dbfit

I get **"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type İNT is not supported"** exception for all types other than varchars.
For example below test runs without any problem:

```
!path lib/*.jar
!define SOCKET_TIMEOUT {300000}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -Ds=${SOCKET_TIMEOUT} -cp %p %m }
!| dbfit.SqlServerTest |
!|Connect | jdbc:sqlserver://***;user=;password=*;databaseName=***|
!|Query|select 'test1' as column_one, '2' as column_two |
|column_one |column_two|
|test1 |2|
```

But below statement gives **"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Type İNT is not supported"** exception

```
!path lib/*.jar
!define SOCKET_TIMEOUT {300000}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -Ds=${SOCKET_TIMEOUT} -cp %p %m }
!| dbfit.SqlServerTest |
!|Connect | jdbc:sqlserver://***;user=;password=*;databaseName=***|
!|Query|select 1 as column_one, 2 as column_two |
|column_one |column_two|
|1|2|
```

I couldn't find any related problem or solution in fitnesse wiki or anyother material.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this problem occurs because of Turkish characters.
The TYPE int is converted to "İNT" not "INT" so it couldn't be found.

I have added **-Duser.language=en** to COMMAND_PATTERN Now it works without any problem.

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {java -Ds=${SOCKET_TIMEOUT} -Duser.language=en -cp %p %m }
```